# Release management of Xamarin using Azure Devops and App center

Tags: azure, xamarin, release-management, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I am researching the best practices of the industry in the release plan of xamarin app. 
We have a small app, an app for the authorization of payment transactions. We are using Azure DevOps and App center.
I would highly appreciate it if anyone can help us to know a few questions.

1. We are using Azure pipelines, with every checkin, we build, there are so many builds in pipeline.
   How you configure the release pipeline, is it trigger with every build or its schedule release?
2. Where you run UI automated tests? In build pipeline, release pipeline, or app center?
3. When we deploy the app in the google play store, we need to mention the bugs that are fixed in this version. How do you manage this part of deployment?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to reduce the number of times it builds, Why don’t you create a release pipeline that only schedules a build to release the apps when there’s a commit made to that branch?
2. I generally do UITests only on releases through the AppCenter.
3. I usually just send the apps over to the External (Android) / TestFlight beta (Android) and not all the way to production. So it gives me a chance to change anything I need.